# Matching Google adwords referrer url

Tags: php, google-ads-api

Hi I am trying to display different content on my site, if the user has visited from my Google Adwords campaign.

I used document.referrer in the Chrome console to find the referrer and placed this info in the code below

If I set the referrer to be Google.com and visit from there then the script performs - however when trying to match with the Google Adwords referrer URL, it doesn't work.

I was thinking I could attempt to match the string length, or just the '/?gclid=' part of the string

```
<?php
// This is to check if the request is coming from a specific URL
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if($ref == 'http://domain.nl/?gclid=CjwKEAiApOq2BRDoo8SVjZHV7TkSJABLe2iDnbfXanR14L-Di0IaoXGFTRx_uF_SGJ6QrmMstGDQChoCbBzw_wcB') {

echo "yes";

}

else {

echo "no";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used preg_match to recognise the gclid string that is in every adwords referrer URL.

This worked - but there was another problem. When the page initially loads the referrer URL is not set - it is only set when navigating to the next page (when the script works).

However when the page first loads, the Adwords referral is in the browser address bar, so I used REQUEST_URI and 'or' to detect the gclid string in the address bar. Here is the code:

```
<?php

if(preg_match('/gclid/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) or preg_match('/gclid/i', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {

echo "adwords visitor content";

}

else {

echo "regular visitor content";

}

?>
```

Comment: how may I use it in .net core c#?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might test if referer has *gclid* parameter (it almost always has different length), but you loose information about WHICH campaign caused that and maybe differ message based on that.

**Like:** if someone just visited from product keyword implying buying intention (like iPhone 6 64 GB Paris) or just general keyword "smart phone"

I propose you to **make use of UTM params**, in this case [AdWords manual tagging](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033981?hl=en), at least for pages you want this content be shown.

url then might be like http://domain.nl/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=content_x